# Datatables no es responsive

Tags: bootstrap, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla, y el problema esta en que cuando es para dispositvos pequeños no se hace responsive.

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/jquery.dataTables.css}" />
    <script th:src="@{/js/jquery.dataTables.js}"></script>
</head>
<table id="ranking" class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="table-info">
        <tr >
            <th>Posición</th>
            <th>Alias</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Puntuación</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- <tr th:each="u,pos: ${usuarios}">
            <th th:text="${pos.count}"></th>
            <th th:text="${u.alias}"></th>
            <th th:text="${u.nombre}"></th>
            <th th:text="${u.puntos}"></th>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
        <th>aaaaaaaaaa</th>
        <th>aaaaaaaaaa</th>
        <th>aaaaaaaaa</th>
        <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</th>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$('#ranking').DataTable( {
    searching : false,
    responsive: true,
    lengthChange : false,
    paging : false,
    info :false,
    language : {
        "url": "/js/spanish.json"
    }
} );

</script>
```

Comment: Deberas buscarte en internet la libreria de jquery-datatables que vuelve responsive la tabla, ademas deberas adicionarle a la clase de la tabal dt-responsive, siempre y cuando tengas los archivos mencionados enlazados. dependiendo el tamaño de tu pantalla el automaticamente te genera el responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a añadir las clases "display responsive no-wrap" a la tabla y fuerza a que tenga un acncho de 100%:

```
<table id="ranking" class="table table-hover display responsive no-wrap" width="100%">
```

---

**UPDATE**

Mira a ver [este caso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500010/responsive-bootstrap-datatable-not-collapsing-columns-at-the-correct-point) si te puede ayudar.

Comment: antes de nada gracias por la respuesta, en cuanto a lo de la tabla probé lo que comentaste y sigue igual

Comment: Si vas a usar la respuesta de alguien más, tradúcela y deja los créditos aquí al autor original

Answer (score 1):

Agrega estos 2 archivos:

css: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/dataTables.responsive.css`

js: `//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.js`

y está bien que le pongas en `responsive: true`

puedes leer este artículo: [responsive](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de ocupar la librería: dataTables.bootstrap.min.js

Para hacer responsiva una tabla, puedes ponerla en un div llamando la clase: table-responsive

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="ranking" class="table table-hover">
     Tu HTML del contenido de la tabla aquí....
   </table>
 </div>
```

De esa manera se ajustaría la tabla en dispositivos pequeños. 
Nota: No va a hacer pequeña la tabla; sino más bien, colocará un escroll horizontal.